# JSON Data in Table View iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, json, tableview

I have to add a Tab in a Tabbar Controller in an iPhone App with a table view what is showing JSON data.

My Problem is now that i see the table view but no data. Here is my code:

.h File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FourthViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tweets;

@end
```

.m File

```
#import "FourthViewController.h"

@interface FourthViewController ()

@end

@implementation FourthViewController

@synthesize myTableView;
@synthesize tweets;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Issue load request after the view has been loaded.
    [self issueLoadRequest];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setMyTableView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)issueLoadRequest
{
    // Dispatch this block asynchronosly. The block gets JSON data from the specified URL and performs the proper selector when done.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=jmenter&count=10"]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receiveData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // When we have the data, we serialize it into native cocoa objects. (The outermost element from twitter is
    // going to be an array. I JUST KNOW THIS. Reload the tableview once we have the data.
    self.tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    // The element in the array is going to be a dictionary. I JUST KNOW THIS. The key for the tweet is "text".
    NSDictionary *tweet = [self.tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Spit out some pretty JSON for the tweet that was tapped. Neato.
    NSString *formattedJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[self.tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"tweet:\n%@", formattedJSON);
}


@end
```

I have used this tut here: http://jeffmenter.wordpress.com/2012/05/30/json-ios-5-go/

Comment: BTW, what is the output when you NSLog (@"twitter: %@",twitter) ?

Answer (score 0):

As it is currently defined, tweet is an NSArray. You should not access its member using `objectForKey` but using `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row`. (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`)

Depending on the data that you receive, you might opt for an NSDictionara for tweet.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the objectforkey "text" in tweet is a string, if not convert it into string using [NSString Stringwithformat:@"%@",[tweet objectForKey:@"text"]];

Answer (score 0):

You should take that JSON data in an object outside table view and than fetch it to table view `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, don't fetch it directly.
Because downloading data takes some time and bad connection is also an problem. So if the data is not getting downloaded the table view will show nothing. So it's better to download it and check it if the data is present by adding breakpoints than try to fetch it.